# Тем, кто дружен, не страшны тревоги

Tags: частица-не, частица

Тем, кто дружен, не страшны тревоги.

Строка из "Песни бременских музыкантов". Скажите, почему "не" решительно пишется раздельно со "страшны"? Приведите, пожалуйста, пример слитного написания и разъясните, каким синонимичным выражением можно будет в этом случае заменить слово "нестрашны"? Обязательно ли наличие синонимичного выражения? И если да, необходимо ли, чтобы оно вписывалось в синтаксис прежложения, в контекст (то есть сочеталось со словами "тем", "тревоги"), предопределена ли форма таких выражений, часть речи?

Comment: Да нету тут никакого сакрального смысла. Обычная орфография, которая допускает оба варианта.

Comment: Тем не менее интересно было бы узнать о необходимости и подборе синонимичных выражений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, причина кроется именно в музыке. Вы же композитор... Вам должно быть это интересно.

Во всей песне используется приём повторения трёх нот одной длительности.

Наш пример - это 3 ноты ля.

Если `нестрашны` написать вместе - то ударение должно падать на букву "А". Чтобы в музыке это произошло - там должна быть синкопа (например, сделать восьмую четвертной). То есть нужно сломать основной ритм песни. Это того явно не стоит.

А в самой песне оно произносится как единое слово "нЕстрашны", так как 3 одинаковых длительности (восьмые). Ударение падает на "Е", потому что это начало такта (сильная доля). Если "не" выделяется интонацией, то обязательно нужно писать отдельно.

Comment: Да, восприятие текста, его синтаксисическое строение зависят от мелодии, на которую он распевается. Это интересно. Но мне все-таки изначально было интересно разобраться в частностях употребления подобного оборота.

Answer (score 0):

***Тем, кто дружен, не страшны тревоги.***

Как писать? **Посмотрим в Нацкорпусе:** раздельно — 449 примеров, слитно — 6 примеров (причем практически все в старых текстах до 1956 года).

Итак, здесь  выбор явно делается в пользу отрицания, а не утверждения: ***тревоги страшны — тревоги не страшны.***

А существует ли вообще прилагательное ***нестрашный***? Да, есть такое.

**НЕСТРАШНЫЙ,**  Такой, который не вызывает страха, не пугает. Н-ая собака. Н-ые истории.

Возможные синонимы: ***безобидный, безопасный, безвредный.***

Но это полное прилагательное: собака ***нестрашная*** (***безобидная*** на вид).

Можно сказать: *собака не страшна?* Нет, пожалуй. Краткая форма этого прилагательного используется **с зависимыми словами**: ***нам*** собака не страшна.

И вот такие краткие формы близки к причастиям, их написание регулируется особым правилом. Розенталь рассматривает различные варианты, когда зависимые слова влияют на раздельное написание НЕ с прилагательными, а также называет  краткие формы, которые всегда пишутся раздельно.

http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77

8. Раздельное написание частицы не с прилагательным, имеющим при себе пояснительные слова, встречается:
   1) при прилагательных, которые в полной и краткой формах имеют разное значение: не готовый к выходу актёр; не склонный к простуде ребёнок;

Comment: Не могу понять: разве слова "готов" и "готовый", "склонный" и "склонен" имеют разные значения? И скажите, необходимо ли, чтобы синонимичное выражение имело ту же форму и часть речи, что и слово, к которому оно подобрано?

Comment: *Краткая форма этого прилагательного используется с зависимыми словами* - не могу понять, откуда такой вывод. Это в общем-то частность, ибо я совсем запутался в ваших пояснениях, но я свои основные вопросы приберегу, чтобы не мешать автору вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

> Тем не менее интересно было бы узнать о необходимости и подборе
>   синонимичных выражений.

Я, возможно, всё еще не до конца понимаю ваши сложности, но если отвечать на вопрос так, как он поставлен, то здесь нет простого и исчерпывающего правила. То есть оно, может, и есть, но, чтобы его сформулировать, надо разбираться с функциями сам**о**й краткой формы (в частности - вводить понятие предикатива) и скрупулезно рассматривать все случаи. Я сделал попытку это как-то причесать, но пункте на десятом отчаялся.
Альтернативой может служить только понятийное, интуитивно понятное правило о том, что с краткими формами (в препозиции как минимум) НЕ пишется раздельно, когда не предполагается образования нового качества. Все остальные ограничения определяются самим существованием форм с НЕ и применимостью в конкретном контексте.
В нашем случае никаких подобных ограничений я не вижу. 
Оба варианта допустимы и различаются только авторским акцентом. 
Каких-то значимых факторов вроде наличия или отсутствия зависимых слов я не наблюдаю.

**Тем, кто дружен, не страшны тревоги** - отрицание того, что тревоги страшные.
**Тем, кто дружен, нестрашны тревоги** - констатация того, что тревоги нестрашные. Последние вызывает вопросы в отношении своего смысла. Ну нестрашные, но какие-такие? Антонима-то подходящего нету у слова "страшный". Бесстрашный? "Тем, кто дружен, бесстрашны тревоги"?! смысл если и есть, то явно не тот, что предполагался. 
То есть антонима нету, а значит, и нет возможности образовать новое качество. Отсюда и написание тяготеет к раздельному. Как-то так...
Фактически вернулись к тому, из чего исходили. Всё на авторское усмотрение.

Уфффф... Все-таки не может правильно поставленный вопрос вызывать такие сложности.
ВЫ уверены, что вам надо все это разложить по полочкам?
Я ведь как рассуждаю. если автор знает, чем различаются в его представлении орфографические варианты (в нашем случае - слитное/раздельное написание), то он просто должен убедится, что желательный вариант не противоречит орфографии (ну или пунктуации). Всё. У нас оба варианта допустимы. 
А если автор в принципе не видит разницы, но знает, что оба варианта возможны, то пусть пишет себе как заблагорассудится. Глубоко копать имеет смысл, если только известно, что варианты различны по смыслу, а автор не понимает, чем. Но это явно не наш случай. Глубоких смысловых различий тут нет. Вон, даже Sharon их не нашла.

Comment: Все изложено довольно ясно. Остается один вопрос: если "новое качество" не может быть представлено синонимом, сохраняется ли возможность слитного написания (что равно вообще отсутствию необходимости в синонимах)?

Answer (score 0):

**Второй ответ** (написание НЕ с краткими прилагательными при наличии зависимого слова).

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77  11. Пишутся раздельно с частицей НЕ краткие формы прилагательных, которые не употребляются в полной форме или имеют **в полной форме иное значение**: *не готов к отъезду; не должен так поступать; не намерен молчать; не обязан помогать; не рад встрече; не склонен верить; не расположен к беседе и др.*

Вот, к примеру, для прилагательного ***готовый*** в словаре указаны 4 основных значения, но только одно из них общее для обеих форм. Еще одно ― только для полной формы, а два другиХ ― только для краткой формы в функции сказуемого (готов на подвиг, готовы ехать, обед готов). Надо ожидать, что написание НЕ в этом случае будет **раздельным**.

Прилагательное ***страшный*** является качественным: собака страшная (огромная, лохматая), собака нестрашная (маленькая, безобидная на вид). Это общая оценка, постоянный признак, характерный для **полных форм.**

**А краткая форма ближе к сказуемому, она называет качество в данный момент**. Кому-то она страшна, кому-то не страшна. То есть качество предмета **может меняться и зависит от воспринимающего субъекта** (его присутствие обозначено зависимым словом в Д.п.).

**Вывод**: краткое прилагательное ***страшен*** (кому-то) приобретает временнУю характеристику, что характерно для сказуемого, поэтому НЕ с прилагательным ***страшен*** в краткой форме при наличии зависимого слова в форме Д.п. пишется    обычно раздельно: ***Тем, кто дружен, не страшны тревоги.*** Без зависимых слов краткое прилагательное ***страшен*** практически не употребляется.

**Примечание.** Краткие формы ***не виден, не слышен***  с раздельным написанием НЕ также используются значительное чаще (слитное написание встречается в единичных случаях). Причина все та же: качество предмета в этом случае связано с его восприятием, а оно меняется во времени и часто относится к конкретному наблюдателю.

Comment: Как-то запутанно. В таком случае временная характеристика - черта всякого краткого прилагательного, и уже этим оно отличается от своей полной формы. Подобный вывод побуждает нас всякое прилагательное в краткой форме писать раздельно с "не".

Comment: Не каждое. Здесь признак особый, связанный с восприятием предмета наблюдателем. При этом каждый может наблюдать  по-своему. Кому-то в данный момент тревоги не страшны, а кого-то очень даже напрягают. Непостоянный это признак. И вот эту мысль вы пропустили. Как-то мы с вами мыслим в разных плоскостях. Одно утешает: может в сетевом пространстве и у меня найдутся единомышленники, хотя как знать. Тогда напрасно трачу время.

Comment: В таком случае и в полной форме признак непостоянен, и в полной форме он зависит от воспринимающего. "Страшная собака". Многие слова выражают субъективное состояние: прекрасный, благолепный, ужасный, некрасивый, радостный и так далее.